# Can string literals be passed in posix_spawn's argv?

Tags: c, posix, string-literals

For [the `posix_spawn` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/posix_spawn.html) its prototype is:

```
int posix_spawn(pid_t *restrict pid, const char *restrict path,
   const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *file_actions,
   const posix_spawnattr_t *restrict attrp,
   char *const argv[restrict], char *const envp[restrict]);
```

Notably, the `argv` parameter points to an array of `char *` pointers (i.e. pointers to mutable characters). Further, the documentation does not seem to give any guarantee that the data will not be written to.

My question is: is there a guarantee somewhere that it is OK to pass a string literal?  Or are we risking a segfault?

Sample code:

```
char *v[] = { "foo.exe", "bar", NULL };
posix_spawn( NULL, "foo.exe", NULL, NULL, v, NULL );
```

Comment: You don't need any explicit guarantee the data won't be written to. Unless the function is specified to modify some object, it doesn't do it.

Comment: @R.. It'd be better if it were explicitly said. I can't imagine why posix_spawn would want to modify the arguments but there are certainly cases where a pointer can be as-if-const (i.e., the target will be written to but changes will be reverted on return). I use such pointers (commenting them as-if-const)  quite a bit for strings where I need to temporarily insert a `\0`.

Comment: @PSkocik: There can't be such cases. Any such implementation would have data races and thereby be non-thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using string literals is perfectly fine here.

Whether a pointer argument (or pointer data pointed to by an argument) points to const-qualified type has nothing to do with whether the function can modify a pointed-to object. This is purely a matter of the contract of the function in question. As a convention, it's usually preferable to use const-qualified pointers in arguments when the object won't be modified:

1. to allow passing pointers to const-qualified objects without casts, and
2. as an indication that the object won't be modified.

but there is no requirement to do so in the C language. And for functions that use double-pointer types in their interfaces, there's often a tradeoff here. Since `T *` and `const T *` cannot alias one another, the interface has to choose the form more likely for the caller to want; if the caller wants the other form, it has to make a temporary copy to pass to the function. This is the case for `posix_spawn`.

In general, when it comes to standard functions (C or POSIX), they **cannot have any observable side effects except as specified**. Unless the DESCRIPTION for the function documents that it will modify an object "belonging to" the application, or which the application has access to, it cannot modify it; doing so is non-conforming. This is why functions which return pointers to static storage explicitly document it. For example, POSIX documents for `strerror`:

> The returned string pointer might be invalidated or the string content might be overwritten by a subsequent call to strerror(),

Short of such documentation, an application could assume that the string returned by `strerror` is never modified by the implementation.

Since `posix_spawn` is not documented to modify the strings pointed to by its `argv` array, it does not modify them.

Further, note that `posix_spawn` is required to be thread-safe, and does not place any explicit constraint on applications for concurrent access to the `argv` strings. As such, any modification would introduce data races, thereby rendering `posix_spawn` non-thread-safe, contrary to specification.

Comment: The line of reasoning is good about standard functions. Yet it does not detail `posix_spawn()` documentation lacks side effects.  Instead, per my reading of "The argv and envp arguments specify the argument list and   environment for the program that is executed in the child process,    as for execve in [posix_spawn](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html), `posix_spawn()` treats `argv` ...

Comment: ....  like [execve](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) which in turn has "The argument vector and environment can be accessed by the called program's main function, when it is defined as:    `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`".  As `main()` `argv` can have its strings pointed to by the argv array modified, it is reasonable to consider, `argv` of `posix_spawn()` incurs the same possibility.

Comment: @chux: For `execve`, that's after the running process image has been completely replaced by the call to exec and *everything has ceased to exist*. Whether it was mutable or not is irrelevant at that point because the original object no longer exists.

Comment: In the case of `posix_spawn`, unlike `execve` the caller does not cease to exist; a child process is created with arguments copied from the `argv` passed to `posix_spawn`. This is a completely different process; modifying the `argv` array received by `main` in the new process has no effect on the `argv` passed to `posix_spawn`. You're wrongly conflating them just because they have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the type was chosen for compatibility with the `char **argv` argument to `main` (and `execve`).  (Although in a traditional implementation with proper process separation, the kernel eventually has to make a copy.)

POSIX does not seem to say that these arrays are modified, but I'm pretty confident that no existing implementation will modify them.  There could be some reasons for using different arguments (and executable names), but those will be *longer*, so `posix_spawn` has to allocate memory for a copy anyway, and cannot perform the modification in-place.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a guarantee somewhere that it is OK to pass a string literal? Or are we risking a segfault?

Given, there is a technical segfault risk as `argv` expects a non-`const` array of `char*` and providing a *string literal* can lead to UB.  With a function   perhaps modeling `main(int argc, char *argv[])`, code can write to `argv[0]`.

> `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
>   ...
>   The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be **modifiable** by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination. C11 §5.1.2.2.1 2

```
int foo(......., char *const argv[restrict], char *const envp[restrict]);

char *v[] = { "foo.exe", "bar", NULL };
foo( NULL, "foo.exe", NULL, NULL, v, NULL );
```

---

**Alternative**

Although with `posix_spawn()`, I doubt a write will occur, a solution with C99 employs a *compound literal* rather than a *string literal* and so avoids UB potential.

```
// char *v[] = { "foo.exe", "bar", NULL };
char *v2[] = { (char [8]){"foo.exe"}, (char [4]){"bar"}, NULL };
posix_spawn( NULL, "foo.exe", NULL, NULL, v2, NULL );
```

Now  `posix_spawn()` can write to `v2[0]`

Comment: This answer is not correct. The presence or absence of a const qualifier in the pointed to type has no relevance to whether the interface can clobber data it's not explicitly specified to modify.

Comment: @R.. [Disagree.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596439/can-string-literals-be-passed-in-posix-spawns-argv/50604922?noredirect=1#comment88222072_50604922)  With parameter `const foo * bar`, code  indicates that it will not modify that data pointed to by `bar` (not without UB).

Comment: I get another warning if I use your alternative suggestion: ` warning: temporary whose address is used as value of member of local variable 'v2' will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling]`

Comment: @NateGlenn Please comment here with a larger sample of code that caused the warning.

Comment: @chux `char* argv[] = {"arg1", "arg2", NULL};` triggers the warning. Just realized I'm using C++ and OP is on C, though. Fix was to do `char arg1[22] = {"arg1"}; char arg2[11] = {"arg2"}; char* argv[] = {arg1, arg2, NULL};` instead, though it's not as pretty.

Comment: @NateGlenn Does `int main(void) { char *v2[] = { (char [8]){"foo.exe"}, (char [4]){"bar"}, NULL }; (void) v2; }` with a C99 or later compiler still warn for you?

Comment: @chux Yes, it generates the warning noted above twice, once for each of the strings. Using C++17.

Comment: @Nate Glenn  Do you get those warnings with a C compiler?  Post is tagged C.

Comment: @chux As I mentioned in my second comment, no, so you can probably ignore this. I happened to find this question while searching for the same issue in C++, so having the workaround posted here will be useful for the next person using C++.

Comment: @NateGlenn Consider posting a C++ question that addresses this issue.